# Sql Server 2016 RevoScaleR Error $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Tags: sql-server, r, revolution-r, sql-server-2016

```
connectionString <- "Driver=SQL Server;Server=xxx;Database=TestDB;Uid=test;Pwd=test"`
    SampleDataTable <- "SampleData"
    sqlRowsPerRead = 5000 

     sampleDataDS <- RxSqlServerData(
     connectionString = connectionString,
     table = SampleDataTable,
     rowsPerRead = sqlRowsPerRead)

     # Read the variable information
     varInfo <- rxGetVarInfo( data = sampleDataDS )

     # Print the variable information
     varInfo
     sqlShareDir <- paste("c:\\AllShare\\", Sys.getenv("USERNAME"), sep="")
     dir.create(sqlShareDir, recursive = TRUE)
     sqlWait <- TRUE
     sqlConsoleOutput <- FALSE
```

## Define compute context

```
        rxSetComputeContext(
          RxInSqlServer(
                connectionString = connectionString,
                 shareDir = sqlShareDir,
                 wait = sqlWait,
                 consoleOutput = sqlConsoleOutput,
                 traceEnabled = TRUE,
                 traceLevel = 7)
        ) 

rxGetVarInfo(data = sampleDataDS)
```

## Error:

```
inTraining <-createDataPartition(c(sampleDataDS$column1,sampleDataDS$column2, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)
```

The "createDataPartition command throws an error, 
Error in sampleDataDS$column1 : 
  $ operator not defined for this S4 class "

Can someone help me with this error? I am not sure how to access the columns within the table that I am loading from SQL Server. Thank You!

Comment: Having same problem :( no solution yet.